# Delete table row jquery

Tags: jquery, removeall

I have this table row

```
<tr role="row" class="even">
    <td class="sorting_1">10</td>
    <td>er</td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-id="1"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i> Delete record</button>
    </td>
    <td>er</td>
</tr>
<tr role="row" class="even">
    <td class="sorting_1">10</td>
    <td>er</td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-id="2"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i> Delete record</button>
    </td>
    <td>er</td>
</tr>
<tr role="row" class="even">
    <td class="sorting_1">10</td>
    <td>er</td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-id="3"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i> Delete record</button>
    </td>
    <td>er</td>
</tr>
```

What i need is when user clicks on delete button of any row then that row should be deleted .

Answer (score 1):

Use `.closest()` and find the **closest tr with respect to button and remove it** as shown below.

```
$('.btn.btn-danger').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();  //or  $(this).closest('tr').hide();
});
```

[Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/78rz40n3/5/)

OR

```
$('.btn.btn-danger').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();  //or  $(this).parent().parent().hide();
});
```

[Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/78rz40n3/6/)

**Complete Code :-**

```js
$('.btn.btn-danger').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();  //or  $(this).closest('tr').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr role="row" class="even">
    <td class="sorting_1">10</td>
    <td>er</td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-id="1"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i> Delete record</button>
    </td>
    <td>er</td>
</tr>
<tr role="row" class="even">
    <td class="sorting_1">10</td>
    <td>er1</td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-id="2"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i> Delete record</button>
    </td>
    <td>er1</td>
</tr>
<tr role="row" class="even">
    <td class="sorting_1">10</td>
    <td>er2</td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-id="3"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i> Delete record</button>
    </td>
    <td>er2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think he is very clear in his requirements . In your fiddle , when i click on the first/second button then also it's deleting from the last .

Comment: @Gorostas...i think this answer will solve your problem if need more help then comment..

Comment: @Gorostas...if answer solved your problem then accept this as answer so that accepted answer helps others also...thanks..